# Creating a DOM variable in Google Tab Manager attached to a meta description in React

Tags: reactjs, variables, dom, google-tag-manager

My website is built in React and I want to create a DOM variable, within GTM, that attaches to the meta description. Trying the usual meta[property="description"] method and it's not working. Any help would be more than welcomed!

Comment: Can you expands "not working"?

Comment: Meta description usually has "name" instead of "property". Since this is an HTML standard, not a react thing, this is the first thing I would check.